# Text not wrapping properly around image in Wordpress Visual Editor

Tags: images

This question pertains specifically to the Wordpress Visual Editor _ 
I have searched for an answer to this question because it must be a common issue_ but sadly not been able to find a solution anywhere_ including Stack Exchange

The problem is getting text to wrap all the way up the side of an image _ I just cannot get it to do it as I would expect it to in webpages that are NOT Wordpress specific _

The display in the visual editor shows the image and text exactly how I want it
[image]

But the text and the image on the actual page looks like this 
[image]

The Wordpress Text Editor code is this

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-301" src="https://www.careerrecruitment.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/workers7-300x159.png" alt="" width="300" height="159" /> Text content </p>
```

If anyone could advise on how to resolve this issue I would be very grateful _

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: try to search for extra `<p>` tags in browser inspect window

Comment: have done so DHL17 but nothing there that shouldn't be _ the most frustrating thing about this is I know I have seen an article on the web that deals with this _ but no sign of it when I actually need it! Thanks for your input

Comment: can you provide me the article link.

Comment: the css you posted has done the trick _ i know i''m not supposed to say thanks in a comment _ nevertheless very grateful : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take advantage of these new CSS classes for image alignment

```
img.alignright { float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em; }
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
img.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.alignright { float: right; }
.alignleft { float: left; }
.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

find here: [Text Wrapping Issue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Wrapping_Text_Around_Images)